# How to get nginx to strip cookies except for an allow list?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cookies

I'm trying to host sites that use things like WordPress, using nginx as a reverse proxy for PHP-FPM. Often these systems will set all kinds of annoying cookies that are unnecessary and/or the site does not have permission to set.

So I'm looking to strip all cookies *except* for those that appear in an allow list. In WordPress for example, I might want to allow only the admin session cookie which is called `wordpress_sec_*`.

I've found the "headers more" extension which has some nice things like:

```
more_clear_headers 'Set-Cookie';
```

which will delete *all* cookies, though that's obviously excessive. I can probably delete specific cookies, but that's a whack-a-mole as plugins keep setting cookies they don't really need.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: Not sure nginx have this option, but pretty sure that a tool like varnish can solve this problem for you (and probably haproxy as well).

Comment: Indeed, some other tool would be better. That said, every cookie in WordPress should be GDPR compliant already. The same can't be said of every plugin or theme though.

Comment: One thought I had is that it’s probably not too complicated to do using nginx’s built in lua support to script it.